# Get JSON key name

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON data: `{"success":"You are welcome"}` that I have named `json` in my JavaScript code.

When I want to alert `You are welcome` I do `json.success`. So now the problem I am facing is that, what about if I want to alert `success`. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: please show the code.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> So now the problem I am facing is that, what about if I want to alert
>   success. Is there a need way to get it ?

If your object is

```
var obj = {"success":"You are welcome"};
```

You can get the array of keys as

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
```

and then print it as

```
console.log( keys[ 0 ] ); //or console.log( keys.join(",") )
```

```js
var obj = {"success":"You are welcome"};
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(keys[0]);
```

Comment: you saved me alot

Answer (score 7):

You mean something like this?

```
keys = Object.keys(json_object)
key_to_use = keys[0];
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this code

```
alert(Object.keys({"success":"You are welcome"})[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're able to do `json.success`, you don't have "JSON data", you have a Javascript Object. JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation, is no more than the serialization of a Javascript object.

As other answers have stated, you can use `Object.keys()` to list the fields of an object.

Answer (score 3):

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) can be called on any JavaScript object to get back a list of keys.